# Is there a way to sum values of the row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL QUERY, where im using `SUM`:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event1` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event2` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event3` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event4` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event5` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count5
FROM `ec_calendar` WHERE Year(`Day`)=2015 AND Month(`Day`)=6
```

The result is:

[image]

But i want `SUM` these colums. Expected result is **17** (3+4+3+3+4).

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then use `+`:

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event1` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event2` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event3` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event4` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
        SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event5` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       ) as cnt
FROM `ec_calendar`
WHERE day >=  '2015-06-01' and day < '2015-07-01'
```

Note that I changed the `WHERE` clause.  This method is more efficient if you have index on `day`.

MySQL treats booleans as integers, so you can write this as:

```
SELECT (SUM(ID_Event1 <> 0) + SUM(ID_Event2 <> 0) +
        SUM(ID_Event3 <> 0) + SUM(ID_Event4 <> 0) + 
        SUM(ID_Event5 <> 0)
       ) as cnt
FROM `ec_calendar`
WHERE day >=  '2015-06-01' and day < '2015-07-01'
```

Comment: One more little question. Is there a way to get data for whole year? Now, in my application, i have to call this query 12 times, for each month. Can be made one query, which returns somethink like this: http://i.imgur.com/gHqTaT3.png

Comment: Just change the `where` clause to be for '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'.

Comment: But this returns me the `SUM` of all months, not a list with each month value, like is on the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the calculated columns.

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event1` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count1,
SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event2` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count2,
SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event3` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count3,
SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event4` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count4,
SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event5` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count5, 
SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event1` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+ 
SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event2` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+ 
SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event3` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event4` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
SUM(CASE WHEN `ID_Event5` != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as total
FROM `ec_calendar` WHERE Year(`Day`)=2015 AND Month(`Day`)=6
```